# How can I compute delta time in a cross platform fashion in C++?

Tags: timer, c++

I need a way to get time for calculating the delta time.

I see that OpenGL and GLFW have methods for it, but unfortunately I can't use them since I need to make server software too.

What is the best way to get the time, without using OpenGL/GLFWs methods? Either in milliseconds or microseconds.

Note: Must be cross platform, preferably in the default c++ 11 library or a part of the boost library.

Comment: Use the chrono import.

Comment: Does it matter to you that basically every possible option will use different platform/OS specific methods under the hood (and thus may be subject to different drifts and inaccuracies), or are you just looking for a way to avoid having to write such an abstraction yourself?

Comment: @JoshPetrie No, doesn't matter, as long as the differences are very minor

Comment: What is the connection between calculating the deltaTime and making server software?  In other words: Why would the method for finding deltaTime affect you making a game server?

Comment: @sakul_ca I will need to calculate the delta time on the server too. Therefore I need a solution that doesn't depend on OpenGL or GLFW

Comment: @Lolums `std::chrono` is painfully broken on several releases of libstdc++, so unless you're on a known good configuration, you're going to have a bad day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard library header [chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono) (available since C++11) provides various clock and duration types you can use to compute time intervals (in theory -- see my footnote and the comments). You probably want `steady_clock`. Your periodic update method would look something like:

```
auto currentTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
auto elapsed = previousTime - currentTime;

... do stuff with elapsed time...
float elapsed_f = elapsed.count();

previousTime = currentTime;
```

(where `previousTime` is a member or some other persistent storage for the time point). The subtraction of two time points will result in a [`duration` object](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration). [This site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock/now) also contains a more concrete example of using the clock mechanism.

If `steady_clock` isn't fine-grained enough for you, you can look at `high_resolution_clock`. However, it's important to test if the clock that backs the high resolution clock is monotonically increasing (check the `is_steady` member function), because it's not guaranteed to be so.

Note that as discussed in the comments, `chrono` has some issues which tend to make it less than ideal for games -- some of them are due to the wording of the standard providing lots of leeway, some of them are just down to poor implementations. Even though it would not be a great answer to your *question*, using platform-specific timer mechanisms (possibly wrapped up on your own abstraction) are likely the better solution to your *problem*.

Comment: `steady_clock` is extremely unlikely to have the resolution for measuring ticks in games. You're more likely to want `high_resolution_clock` as you noted, except of course it's not _guaranteed_ to be the highest resolution clock on the system (it might even just be an alias for `system_clock` or `steady_clock`). Your best bet - even at the end of 2015 - is still to use the platform-specific timers.

Comment: Josh Petrie How can I convert auto to a primitive?


@SeanMiddleditch I guess I could just go with the platform specific if there's no reliable cross-platform. Which should I use for windows?

Comment: @KareeZ: the usual go-to on Windows is `QueryPerformanceCounter`, which is how a "good" implementation of `high_resolution_clock` works under the hood (note: MSVC 2013 did not in fact have a good implementation, though MSVC 2015's is).

Comment: @SeanMiddleditch That's fine, because I use VS15. Could you please quickly explain how I work with this 'auto' type?

Comment: @KareeZ: not in a comment, no, but you can Google it trivially.

Comment: @KaareZ [auto does not need to be "converted"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto). Sean is correct about `steady_clock`; timing is simple enough that implementing it yourself with platform-specific methods is not difficult and usually results in better results for your specific scenarios. It's what I'd do, personally.